# Python Beginner - where comes <bound method ... of <... object at 0x0000000005EAAEB8>> from?

Tags: python, properties

I have a class

```
class ActivationResult(object):

    def __init__(self, successful : bool):
        self._successful = successful

    def getSuccessful(self) -> bool:
        return self._successful
```

And a test

```
def testSuccessfulFromCreate(self):

    target = ActivationResult(True)

    self.assertEquals(target._successful, True)
    self.assertEquals(target.getSuccessful, True)
```

The first assert is good, but the second one fails with `AssertionError: <bound method ActivationResult.getSuccess[84 chars]EB8>> != True`

The same thing happens, when I try to print it. Why?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you're comparing **the method itself**, rather than the value it would return if called. Also, there's no need for get/set in Python; either access the attribute directly or use a `@property`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I tried to use https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/ as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21384492/254041 (and it doesn't produce any errors or warnings).

Comment: @PM2Ring that's a function annotation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting the method, not calling it.
Try :

```
self.assertEquals(target.getSuccessful(), True)  # With parenthesss
```

It's OK the first time because you get the attribute `_successful`, which was correctly initialized with `True`.
But when you call `target.getSuccessful` it *gives* you the method object *itself*, where it seems like you want to actuall **call** that method.

---

**Explanation**

Here is an example of the same thing that happens when you print an object's method:

```
class Something(object):
    def somefunction(arg1, arg2=False):
        print("Hello SO!")
        return 42
```

We have a class, with a method.
Now if we print it, but **not calling** it :

```
s = Something()
print(s.somefunction)  # NO parentheses
>>> <bound method Something.somefunction of <__main__.Something object at 0x7fd27bb19110>>
```

We get the same output `<bound method ... at 0x...>` as in your issue. This is just how the method is represented when printed itself.

Now if we print it and actually **call** it:

```
s = Something()
print(s.somefunction())  # WITH parentheses
>>>Hello SO!
>>>42
```

The method is called (it prints `Hello SO!`), and its return is printed too (`42`)

Comment: Well I realize it might just be a typo and you forgot the parentheses, but as you've put "beginner" in the title I thought I'd explain something I hope useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - very helpful for a deeper understanding.