# Unable to get value from a getter method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning Python. Due to some performance issue I have to switch all codes from Java to Python in one of my AWS Lambda functions. I am using the IDE provided by the lambda console.

Currently, I am a little stuck on classes in Python. I read a number of tutorials and I think what I did on setters and getters method are correct. Here is my code:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.username = user

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def set_username(self, user):
        self.username = user

def lambda_handler(request, context):
    user = User("thisisaname")
    print("name of user is " + user.get_username)
    user.set_username("whatever")
    print("name of user is " + user.get_username)
    return "executed"
```

When lambda_handler gets called, I am expecting the output to be

```
name of user is thisisname
name of user is whatever
```

However, when I am printing the value of user.get_username. TypeError is thrown. The following error message is what I got:

```
{   "errorMessage": "can only concatenate str (not \"method\") to str",   "errorType": "TypeError",   "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 28, in lambda_handler\n    print(\"name of user is \" + user.get_username)\n" ] }
```

When I wrap it with a str(user.get_username), the method description is printed.

```
name of user is <bound method User.get_username of <lambda_function.User object at 0x7f4d6a4cc4d0>> 
name of user is <bound method User.get_username of <lambda_function.User object at 0x7f4d6a4cc4d0>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Beginner - where comes <bound method ... of <... object at 0x0000000005EAAEB8>> from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879886/python-beginner-where-comes-bound-method-of-object-at-0x0000000005ea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not *calling* the getter method. Change it to:

```
print("name of user is " + user.get_username())
```

That being said, Python idiomatically doesn't have getters and setters as in Java. The *Pythonic* way to do it is to use the `@property` decorators. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627034/2011147) for details.