# Accept only objects in a method and return new object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, fractions

I want to create a method that only takes objects of the class it is is defined in, manipulates it and returns a new object of the same class.

For example:

```
class fraction():
    def__init__(self, counter, denominator):
        self.counter=counter
        self.denominator=denominator
    
    def add(self,(object of class fraction))
        (addition of object the method from called in and the object which is called in the  method
        return (new object of the class fraction)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get this done?
best regards,
David

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: You can also implement the class' special methods, such as `__add__()`, so that you can use operators with your class.

Comment: The only way to do this is to check the argument in the function/method before trying to use it - then you have to decide what to do if it is not the correct type, like raise a ValueError.

Comment: Does [How do Python functions handle the types of the parameters that you pass in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489669/how-do-python-functions-handle-the-types-of-the-parameters-that-you-pass-in) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, counter, denominator):
        self.counter = counter
        self.denominator = denominator

    def add(self, fraction):
        return Fraction(self.counter * fraction.denominator + fraction.counter * self.denominator,
                        self.denominator * fraction.denominator)


a = Fraction(2, 3)
b = Fraction(3, 5)
a_plus_b = a.add(b)
print(a_plus_b.counter, a_plus_b.denominator)
```

You can add type checking directly in the add function :

```
def add(self, fraction):
        if not isinstance(fraction, Fraction):
            raise TypeError(f"{fraction} is not a Fraction.")
        return Fraction(self.counter * fraction.denominator + fraction.counter * self.denominator,
                        self.denominator * fraction.denominator)
```

If you want to integrate this in the standard fractions module, you can make a class inheriting from fractions.Fraction, which will outpute you a nice irreductible fraction :

```
import fractions


class MyFraction(fractions.Fraction):

    def add(self, fraction):
        return MyFraction(self.numerator * fraction.denominator + fraction.numerator * self.denominator,
                        self.denominator * fraction.denominator)


a = MyFraction(2, 3)
b = MyFraction(10, 6)
a_plus_b = a.add(b)
print(a_plus_b.numerator, a_plus_b.denominator)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!Two more questions: 
1.) It works great but it does not check if the argument is the right type. How can I check if the argument is an object of the class Fraction?
2.) Can I combine this with the Fraction module?

Comment: You can add type checking directly in the add function

Comment: (1/2) Since Python is dynamically typed, there's no concept of restricting a function to have specific argument types. Arguments can be *any* type; it's the function's job to determine how to *use* them. Think of it as a form of implicit overloading: the same `add` function can handle `a.add(Fraction(3,5)` and `a.add(5)`, by checking at runtime if `b` is another `Fraction` or an `int`.

Comment: (2/2) That said, you can use type hints and `mypy` to check *statically* if you are writing code that passes the "wrong" type of argument at compile time. (For example, `a.add("foo")`.)