# python: specify class argument type

Tags: python, class

I have this class:

```
class Transaction:
    
    def __init__(self, date, value, concept : str = ""):
        self.date = date
        self.value =value
        self.concept = concept

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    transaction = Transaction(date=1,value=1,concept=1)
    print(transaction)
    print(type(transaction.concept))
```

I want `Transaction.concept` to be a `str`, but as you can see below, it accepts `1`:

```
<__main__.Transaction object at 0x0000023AEAB88BE0>
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you think you need to change?

Comment: Note that type hints are *hints*, they are not enforced by the interpreter. If you want to check that you have a string, check it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489669/how-do-python-functions-handle-the-types-of-parameters-that-you-pass-in/21384492#21384492) question can help you understand python typing. Quote from this link:

> Python does not have variables, like other languages where variables have a type and a value; it has names pointing to objects, which know their type.

So, if you will run

```py
def func(arg: str):
    print(type(arg))
func(1)
```

You will get

```py
<class 'int'>
```

My suggestion for your code it to use explicit type conversion

```py
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, date, value, concept : str = ""):
        self.date = date
        self.value = value
        self.concept = str(concept)
```

Comment: The question you mention is very useful, so I select your answer. However, in my particular full code, your suggestion is not acceptable.