# How to write a python function that takes in parameters an element without a specific type and a list of the type of this element?

Tags: python

How can I  write a python function that takes in parameters `elt` (that can be of any type) and list of elements of the same type as `elt` ?

```py
def myfunction(elt, l: list[type(elt)]:
    # some code here
```

I want to avoid something like

```py
for el in elt:
    assert type(el) == type(elt)
```

Comment: def myfunction(elt, *elt):   ?

Comment: Sound like a job of type annotation & static analysis tools.

Comment: If you want the compiler to enforce the type, it won't : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21384492/20128192

Comment: Type hinting is just that - a hint. Your IDE / linter will highlight calls to your function with inappropriate types as being potential errors but that won't stop you from running your code. If you want runtime validation then you'll need to do that yourself. Also, bear in mind that *assert()* is only effective when \_\_debug__ is True. If \_\_debug__ is False - i.e., when your script is executed with the -O option, then *assert()* is a noop

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are usually homogeneous - i.e., all elements are of the same type. Many will argue that they always should be thus but the language does not enforce this paradigm.

If you want to ensure that the list is both homogeneous and that the types of its elements are identical to some other point of reference then you'll need to write some code.

If you're only concerned with checking at debug level then you could use *assert()* as follows:

```
from typing import Any

def func(x: Any, y: list[Any]) -> None:
    assert all(isinstance(x, type(_y)) for _y in y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is focused on type hints, then we can use generics.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def myfunction(elt: T, lst: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    return [*lst, elt]  # or whatever it should return


myfunction(1, [1, 2, 3])
myfunction('a', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
myfunction(1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])  # this will fail type check
```

Mypy check will pass for two first calls to `myfunction`, but will fail on the third one.

```
$ mypy code.py
code.py:12: error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "myfunction"  [misc]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: However, mypy 1.9.0 does not detect *myfunction('a', ['a', 'b', 1])* as being a problem

Comment: @CtrlZ good point! I wonder why it happens and how to fix it.